# $\operatorname{Tr}(A^2) \geq-2$, if $A\in SL(2,R)$

Tags: matrices, trace

I saw as a hint to an exercise that if $A\in SL(2,R)$ then
$$\operatorname{Tr}(A^2)\geq-2.$$

I did the exercise with this hint, but I can't prove why this is true. Also, is there a similar inequality to $A\in SL(3,R)$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are the (complex) eigenvalues of $A$, then $\lambda\mu=\det(A)=1$, hence
$$\mathrm{tr}(A^2)=\lambda^2+\mu^2=(\lambda+\mu)^2-2\lambda\mu=\mathrm{tr}(A)^2-2\geq-2$$
Note that $\mathrm{tr}(A)$ is real even if $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are not.

Comment: what a great solution! thanks @carmicheal561 !!

Comment: No problem. I'd be interested if there is an analogue for $\mathrm{SL}_3(\mathbb{R})$, but I don't see one at the moment.

Comment: For $3\times 3$ matrices the Newton identities between power sums $s_k=tr(A^k)$ of the eigenvalues and coefficients $c_k$ of the characteristic polynomial are $$-c_2=s_1, ~~  -2c_1=s_2+c_2s_1=s_2-s_1^2, ~~ -3c_0=s_3+c_2s_2+c_1s_1$$ so that\begin{align}
-tr(A^3)&=c_2\,tr(A^2)+c_1\,tr(A)+3c_0\\
&=\frac12\,tr(A)^3-\frac32\,tr(A)\,tr(A^2)+3c_0.
\end{align} 
No obvious conclusion for $A\in SL(3,\Bbb R)$ with $c_0=1$ is visible.